# Can I remove the ListItem JSON-LD schema from WooCommerce site?

Tags: wordpress, schema.org

I am trying to remove

```
{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"name":"Shop","item":"https://*******/shop/"},
```

Is there a good solution for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The ListItem data is generated here:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-structured-data.php#L391

You can use the filter `woocommerce_structured_data_breadcrumblist` to change the generated structured data, such as removing parts of it.

Use add_filter to add a filter function that overrides the returned markup, returning an empty array.

```php
function f( $markup, $breadcrumbs ){ 
   return array();
} 
add_filter('woocommerce_structured_data_breadcrumblist', 'f', 10, 2);
```